# How to enumerate hosts in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am new to using Ansible and using it to automate the configuration of master slave node clusters.

I have a hosts file split into two groups:

```
[master]
masternode

[slaves]
slavenode0
slavenode1
```

What I would like to to is iterate through the slaves group such that a line in  a file on the remote machine is updated with the index of the position in the slaves group.

When I tried to do this using 'with_items' or with 'with_indexed_items' the problem is that the file gets updated on each machine in the slaves group, corresponding to the amount of slavenodes in the slaves group.  This means that every file on every slavenode ends up with exactly the same line inserted, just that the file was updated x times.

So I want:

```
| slave node | filename | line in file     |
| slave0     |  test    | slave index is 0 |
| slave1     |  test    | slave index is 1 |
```

What I got was:

```
| slave node | filename | line in file     |
| slave0     |  test    | slave index is 1 |
| slave1     |  test    | slave index is 1 |
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit**
After re-reading your question, i think i had misunderstood it.

To get the index of the **current** host within an inventory group, you can use the `index` method on the groups list.

```
{{groups['slaves'].index(inventory_hostname)}}
```

Example

```
- lineinfile:
    path: ~/test
    line: "slave index is {{groups['slaves'].index(inventory_hostname)}}"
```

**Original answer**
If you use [jinja2](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_templating.html) templates with ansible you can access the index in a [for loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for) with `{{loop.index}}`.

An example template for your slave configuration could be look like this

```
| slave node | filename | line in file |
{% for slave in groups['slaves'] %}
| {{slave}} | test | slave index is {{loop.index}} |
{% endfor %}
```

This should have the desired output

```
| slave node | filename | line in file |
| slavenode0 | test | slave index is 1 |
| slavenode1 | test | slave index is 2 |
```

To use this in your playbook you use the ansible [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) module.

```
tasks:
  - name: master slave configuration
    template: src=slave.conf.j2 dest=/etx/slave.conf
```

Comment: Glad to help! In order to improve searchability maybe it'd be good to edit the title of the question, but I don't want to do it without your feedback...

Comment: Sure feel free, I found it hard to describe the problem, so if you have something better, have at it!

Answer (score 2):

you could run the play towards the `localhost` and when it comes to the `lineinfile` task, you should add the `delegate_to` option to run the task to each of the hosts.

You didnt include the `lineinfile` code, so i cant adjust it for you, but you can see example below that demonstrates how the index increments per host:

```
- name: Print index of each host
  shell: "wall 'this is iteration: #{{ index_no}}'"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['is_hosts'] }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: index_no
```

hope it helps