# Loop over a counter across hosts in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to create a configuration file in a few target machines. In the local machine, I am supposed to assign a private IP to each host incrementally.

My stupid brain thought this was simple, so I did this but this failed miserably. I think this is a variable scope problem between the hosts. So, incrementing them within the template is not going to help. Need a way to use a variable that could be present in all hosts, and can be incremented from within the template.

Any thoughts?

```
- name: mock Playbook
  hosts: all
  vars:
    counter: 1
  tasks:
    - name: Template configuration
      template:
        src: server.j2
        dest: /tmp/server.conf
```

Here is my template file(`server.j2`):

```
Address = {{ '10.0.0.' + counter |string }}

{% set counter = counter + 1 %}
```

Now, all the hosts have the same IP assigned in the config file that is:

```
#in the 1st host
cat /tmp/server.conf
Address = 10.0.0.1

#in the 2nd host
cat /tmp/server.conf
Address = 10.0.0.1

#in the 3rd host
cat /tmp/server.conf
Address = 10.0.0.1
```

I was hoping something like this:

```
#in the 1st host
cat /tmp/server.conf
Address = 10.0.0.1

#in the 2nd host
cat /tmp/server.conf
Address = 10.0.0.2

#in the 3rd host
cat /tmp/server.conf
Address = 10.0.0.3
```

inventory file:

```
all:
  children:
    server:
      hosts:
        vm1:
          ansible_host: 192.168.122.173
          ansible_user: ansibleprime
          ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/ansibleprime/.ssh/id_ed25519

    client:
      hosts:
        vm2:
          ansible_host: 192.168.122.87
          ansible_user: ansibleprime
          ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/ansibleprime/.ssh/id_ed25519

        vm3:
          ansible_host: 192.168.122.233
          ansible_user: ansibleprime
          ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /home/ansibleprime/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Comment: So you've got some static IPs for remote VMs, and you want to deploy a `server.conf` file with a "generated" `10.0.0.{{ counter }}` IP to each of them, right?

Comment: yes...you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options on how to assign an index to a host.

1. For example, you can take an index from the list of all hosts

```yaml
  idx0: 1
  idx: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) + idx0 }}"
```

Given the inventory

```yaml
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

you get

```yaml
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - test_01
  - test_02
  - test_03
```

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  idx: '1'
ok: [test_02] => 
  idx: '2'
ok: [test_03] => 
  idx: '3'
```

Then, you can use the filter [ansible.utils.ipaddr](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/ipaddr_filter.html) and get the IP address. For example,

```yaml
  net: 10.0.0.0/24
  ip: "{{ net|ansible.utils.ipaddr(idx) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_02] => 
  ip: 10.0.0.2/24
ok: [test_01] => 
  ip: 10.0.0.1/24
ok: [test_03] => 
  ip: 10.0.0.3/24
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    net: 10.0.0.0/24
    idx0: 1
    idx: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) + idx0 }}"
    ip: "{{ net|ansible.utils.ipaddr(idx) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: idx

    - debug:
        var: ip
```

---

2. The next option is to create a dictionary with the indexes

```yaml
  idx0: 1
  idx: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                zip(range(idx0, ansible_play_hosts_all|length + idx0))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  idx:
    test_01: 1
    test_02: 2
    test_03: 3
```

Then, use this dictionary to get the IP address

```yaml
  net: 10.0.0.0/24
  ip: "{{ net|ansible.utils.ipaddr(idx[inventory_hostname]) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  ip: 10.0.0.1/24
ok: [test_02] => 
  ip: 10.0.0.2/24
ok: [test_03] => 
  ip: 10.0.0.3/24
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    net: 10.0.0.0/24
    idx0: 1
    idx: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                  zip(range(idx0, ansible_play_hosts_all|length + idx0))) }}"
    ip: "{{ net|ansible.utils.ipaddr(idx[inventory_hostname]) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: idx
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: ip
```

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir, as always for saving the day!

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me. :

```
Address = {{ '10.0.0.' + (groups['all'].index(inventory_hostname) +1) |string }}
```

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50446872/5584716) answer.